# Coverity. Configure to ignore certain sections of the source code

Tags: coverity

Looking for a way to configure coverity to ignore certain code sections.
For example let's say I have source code with `func1` and `func2`.
I don't want coverity to analyse `func1`, but I still want it to analyse `func2`.
Is there a way to do that?
Is there a special inline comment that I can add perhaps?

```
int func1(int* value)
{
   *value++;

  return 0;
}
```

```
int func2(int* value)
{
 *value--;

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can exclude a section of C/C++ code using the `__COVERITY__` preprocessor macro, which is defined by the Coverity compiler.  For example, to exclude `func1` but include `func2` in the analysis, do something like:

```
#ifndef __COVERITY__           // <-- added
int func1(int* value)
{
   *value++;

  return 0;
}
#endif                         // <-- added

int func2(int* value)
{
 *value--;

 return 0;
}
```

Related:

- [Synopsys Community support question "Ignore specific function"](https://community.synopsys.com/s/question/0D534000043bZf5CAE/ignore-specific-function), which also describes using `__COVERITY__`.
- [Synopsys Support article "How to exclude the specific path or files from being analyzed"](https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/How-to-exclude-the-specific-path-or-files-from-being-analyzed), which describes the `skip_file` directive, which can be used to exclude entire files.
- [SO question "What preprocessor symbols does Coverity define for a build using 'cov-build'?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719379/what-preprocessor-symbols-does-coverity-define-for-a-build-using-cov-build), which it turns out is asking a similar question to this one, although that is not clear from the title (as it references a presumed solution rather than describing the problem), and hence I don't consider it a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Using the pre processor macro "**COVERITY**" works great!

Also to ignore a single line one can use the //coverity[EVENT_TAG_NAME] method as outlined in the following link

https://doclazy.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/coverity-suppressing-false-positives-with-cod/

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: If my answer contains the information you wanted to know, you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can easily see that the question has been answered.