# Can you #pragma suppress in IAR

Tags: c, misra, coverity

I use Coverity static analysis which is integrated with IAR 8.50.

Is it possible for me to use #pragma suppress for certain files in IAR? How do I do that? Or can I do it in Coverity?

Comment: I don't think `#pragma` can be used for this purpose, but the question [Coverity. Configure to ignore certain sections of the source code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64242723/2659307) and its answer may help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coverity. Configure to ignore certain sections of the source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242723/coverity-configure-to-ignore-certain-sections-of-the-source-code)